# Record Type Selection in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm trying to create record Type selection screen in LWC, but getting this error

**afterRender threw an error in 'c:createContact' [Cannot read property 'recordTypeInfos' of undefined]**

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-combobox name="recordType" label="Record Type" placeholder="Choose Status"
                        value={value} 
                        options={recordTypeId}>

    </lightning-combobox>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import CONTACT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Contact';

export default class CreateContact extends LightningElement {

    @track statusOptions;
    @track value;
    @api objectApiName;

    @track objectInfo;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CONTACT_OBJECT,})
    objectInfo;


    get recordTypeId() {
        // Returns a map of record type Ids 
        console.log(this.objectInfo);
        const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
        return rtis;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.objectInfo));` to see what data you have.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First thing i would do is put the combobox inside a div and only open it up once the wire data for recordtype comes from the object.

```
<div if:true={objectInfo.data}>
<lightning-combobox name="recordType" label="Record Type" placeholder="Choose Status"
value={value} 
options={recordTypeId1}>
</lightning-combobox>
</div>
```

Secondly in javascript where you are constructing the combobox for UI ,you need to match the format of [`lightning combobox`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/example) specified in its documentation

```
 get recordTypeId1() {
      var recordtypeinfo = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
      var uiCombobox = [];
      console.log("recordtype" + recordtypeinfo);
      for(var eachRecordtype in  recordtypeinfo)//this is to match structure of lightning combo box
      {
        if(recordtypeinfo.hasOwnProperty(eachRecordtype))
        uiCombobox.push({ label: recordtypeinfo[eachRecordtype].name, value: recordtypeinfo[eachRecordtype].name })
      }
      console.log('uiCombobox' + JSON.stringify(uiCombobox));
    return uiCombobox;
  }
```

Once the wire data comes back the combobox will openup in markup and your getter function will run

```
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CONTACT_OBJECT}) objectInfo;
```

Also the default value for the combo box UI, put a value which is in your object.

```
@track value = 'Client User';
```

Comment: Its working, but if I remove the if condition from the div then why I'm getting "afterRender threw an error in 'c:createContact' [Cannot read property 'recordTypeInfos' of undefined]" error?

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper - its a race condition, the wire data has not come back and you are trying to access objectInfo data through the getter expression function recordTypeId, thats why you need to open up the getter once the data comes back

Comment: Thanks for answer

Comment: Consider replacing the `<div>` with `<template>` to avoid influencing the rendered DOM structure

Comment: FYI if you like concise syntax you can use `Object.keys(recordtypeinfo).map(id => { value: id, label: recordtypeinfo[id].name })`. The cautious might wish to `.filter(id => { return recordtypeinfo[id].available })` before calling `.map`.